# lstm:Input batch size 100 doesn't match hidden[0] batch size 1

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, lstm, batch-processing

I am trying to add an lstm layer to my previous working AI model.
On adding the model I am getting this error when training the batch to my AI.

earlier without the LSTM the error was not there and it worked fine.

Input batch size 100 doesn't match hidden[0] batch size 1.

I am using nn.LSTMCell

can anyone please help a check if I am missing some parameter to init my lstmcell so it can take batch inputs as well.

below is my code...

```
import os
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from random import random as rndm
from torch.autograd import Variable
from collections import deque

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\granthjain\\Desktop\\startup_code")

torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.DoubleTensor')

class ReplayBuffer(object):

  def __init__(self, max_size=1e6):
    self.storage = []
    self.max_size = max_size
    self.ptr = 0

  def add(self, transition):
    if len(self.storage) == self.max_size:
      self.storage[int(self.ptr)] = transition
    else:
      self.storage.append(transition)
    self.ptr = (self.ptr + 1) % self.max_size
    
  def sample(self, batch_size):
    
    ind = np.random.randint(0, self.ptr, size=batch_size)
    batch_states, batch_next_states, batch_actions, batch_rewards, batch_dones = [], [], [], [], []
    for i in ind: 
      state, next_state, action, reward, done = self.storage[i]
      
      if state is None:
          continue
      elif next_state is None:
          continue
      elif action is None:
          continue
      elif reward is None:
          continue
      elif done is None:
          continue
          
      batch_states.append(np.array(state, copy=False))
      batch_next_states.append(np.array(next_state, copy=False))
      batch_actions.append(np.array(action, copy=False))
      batch_rewards.append(np.array(reward, copy=False))
      batch_dones.append(np.array(done, copy=False))

    return np.array(batch_states,dtype=object).astype(float), np.array(batch_next_states,dtype=object).astype(float), np.array(batch_actions,dtype=object).astype(float), np.array(batch_rewards,dtype=object).astype(float), np.array(batch_dones,dtype=object).astype(float)

class Actor(nn.Module):
  
  def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, max_action):
    super(Actor, self).__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTMCell(state_dim, 256)
    self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(256, 400)
    self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(400, 300)
    self.layer_3 = nn.Linear(300, action_dim)
    self.hx = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.cx = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.max_action = max_action

  def forward(self, x):
    self.hx, self.cx = self.lstm(x, (self.hx, self.cx))
    x = F.relu(self.layer_1(self.hx))
    x = F.relu(self.layer_2(x))
    x = self.max_action * torch.tanh(self.layer_3(x))
    return x


class Critic(nn.Module):
  
  def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim):
    super(Critic, self).__init__()
    # Defining the first Critic neural network
    self.lstm1 = nn.LSTMCell(state_dim + action_dim, 256)
    self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(256, 400)
    self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(400, 300)
    self.layer_3 = nn.Linear(300, 1)
    # Defining the second Critic neural network
    self.lstm2 = nn.LSTMCell(state_dim + action_dim, 256)
    self.layer_4 = nn.Linear(256, 400)
    self.layer_5 = nn.Linear(400, 300)
    self.layer_6 = nn.Linear(300, 1)
    self.hx1 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.cx1 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.hx2 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.cx2 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    
  def forward(self, x, u):
    xu = torch.cat([x, u], 1)
    # Forward-Propagation on the first Critic Neural Network
    self.hx1,self.cx1 = self.lstm(xu, (self.hx1, self.cx1))
    x1 = F.relu(self.layer_1(self.hx1))
    x1 = F.relu(self.layer_2(x1))
    x1 = self.layer_3(x1)
    # Forward-Propagation on the second Critic Neural Network
    self.hx2,self.cx2 = self.lstm(xu, (self.hx2, self.cx2))
    x2 = F.relu(self.layer_4(self.hx2))
    x2 = F.relu(self.layer_5(x2))
    x2 = self.layer_6(x2)
    return x1, x2

  def Q1(self, x, u):
    xu = torch.cat([x, u], 1)
    self.hx1,self.cx1 = self.lstm(xu, (self.hx1, self.cx1))
    x1 = F.relu(self.layer_1(self.hx1))
    x1 = F.relu(self.layer_2(x1))
    x1 = self.layer_3(x1)
    return x1

# Selecting the device (CPU or GPU)
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Building the whole Training Process into a class

class TD3(object):
  
  def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, max_action):
    self.actor = Actor(state_dim, action_dim, max_action).to(device)
    self.actor_target = Actor(state_dim, action_dim, max_action).to(device)
    self.actor_target.load_state_dict(self.actor.state_dict())
    self.actor_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.actor.parameters())
    self.critic = Critic(state_dim, action_dim).to(device)
    self.critic_target = Critic(state_dim, action_dim).to(device)
    self.critic_target.load_state_dict(self.critic.state_dict())
    self.critic_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.critic.parameters())
    self.max_action = max_action

  def reset_hxcx(self):
    self.actor.cx = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.actor.hx = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.actor_target.cx = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.actor_target.hx = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.critic.cx1 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.critic.cx2 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.critic.hx1 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.critic.hx2 = torch.zeros(1,256)    
    self.critic_target.cx1 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.critic_target.cx2 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.critic_target.hx1 = torch.zeros(1,256)
    self.critic_target.hx2 = torch.zeros(1,256)      

  def select_action(self, state):
    print("state =", type(state))
    return self.actor(state).cpu().data.numpy().flatten()

  def train(self, replay_buffer, iterations, batch_size=50, discount=0.99, tau=0.005, policy_noise=0.2, noise_clip=0.5, policy_freq=2):
    
    for it in range(iterations):
      
      # Step 4: We sample a batch of transitions (s, s’, a, r) from the memory
      batch_states, batch_next_states, batch_actions, batch_rewards, batch_dones = replay_buffer.sample(batch_size)
      
      batch_states=batch_states.astype(float)
      batch_next_states=batch_next_states.astype(float)
      batch_actions=batch_actions.astype(float)
      batch_rewards=batch_rewards.astype(float)
      batch_dones=batch_dones.astype(float)
      
      state = torch.from_numpy(batch_states)
      next_state = torch.from_numpy(batch_next_states)
      action = torch.from_numpy(batch_actions)
      reward = torch.from_numpy(batch_rewards)
      done = torch.from_numpy(batch_dones)
      
#      print("actor cx:",self.actor.cx)
#      print("actor hx:",self.actor.hx)
#      print("actor_target cx:",self.actor_target.cx)
#      print("actor_target cx:",self.actor_target.cx)
#      print("self.critic.cx1:",self.critic.cx1)
#      print("self.critic.cx2",self.critic.cx2)
#      print("self.critic.hx1:",self.critic.hx1)
#      print("self.critic.hx2:",self.critic.hx2)
#      print("self.critic_target.cx1:",self.critic_target.cx1)
#      print("self.critic_target.hx1",self.critic_target.hx1)
#      print("self.critic_target.cx2:",self.critic_target.cx2)
#      print("self.critic_target.hx2:",self.critic_target.hx2)

      # Step 5: From the next state s’, the Actor target plays the next action a’
      next_action = self.actor_target(next_state)
      
      # Step 6: We add Gaussian noise to this next action a’ and we clamp it in a range of values supported by the environment
      noise = torch.Tensor(batch_actions).data.normal_(0, policy_noise).to(device)
      noise = noise.clamp(-noise_clip, noise_clip)
      next_action = (next_action + noise).clamp(-self.max_action, self.max_action)
      
      # Step 7: The two Critic targets take each the couple (s’, a’) as input and return two Q-values Qt1(s’,a’) and Qt2(s’,a’) as outputs
      target_Q1, target_Q2 = self.critic_target(next_state, next_action)
      
      # Step 8: We keep the minimum of these two Q-values: min(Qt1, Qt2)
      target_Q = torch.min(target_Q1, target_Q2).double()
      
      
      
      
      # Step 9: We get the final target of the two Critic models, which is: Qt = r + γ * min(Qt1, Qt2), where γ is the discount factor

      done = done.resize_((done.shape[0],1))

      reward = reward.resize_((reward.shape[0],1))

      target_Q = reward + ((1 - done) * discount * target_Q).detach()

      
      
      # Step 10: The two Critic models take each the couple (s, a) as input and return two Q-values Q1(s,a) and Q2(s,a) as outputs
      current_Q1, current_Q2 = self.critic(state, action)

      # Step 11: We compute the loss coming from the two Critic models: Critic Loss = MSE_Loss(Q1(s,a), Qt) + MSE_Loss(Q2(s,a), Qt)
      critic_loss = F.mse_loss(current_Q1, target_Q) + F.mse_loss(current_Q2, target_Q)
      
      # Step 12: We backpropagate this Critic loss and update the parameters of the two Critic models with a SGD optimizer
      self.critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
      critic_loss.backward()
      self.critic_optimizer.step()
      
      # Step 13: Once every two iterations, we update our Actor model by performing gradient ascent on the output of the first Critic model
      if it % policy_freq == 0:
        actor_loss = -self.critic.Q1(state, self.actor(state)).mean()
        self.actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward()
        self.actor_optimizer.step()
        
        # Step 14: Still once every two iterations, we update the weights of the Actor target by polyak averaging
        for param, target_param in zip(self.actor.parameters(), self.actor_target.parameters()):
          target_param.data.copy_(tau * param.data + (1 - tau) * target_param.data)
        
        # Step 15: Still once every two iterations, we update the weights of the Critic target by polyak averaging
        for param, target_param in zip(self.critic.parameters(), self.critic_target.parameters()):
          target_param.data.copy_(tau * param.data + (1 - tau) * target_param.data)
  
  # Making a save method to save a trained model
  def save(self, filename, directory):
    torch.save(self.actor.state_dict(), '%s/%s_actor.pth' % (directory, filename))
    torch.save(self.critic.state_dict(), '%s/%s_critic.pth' % (directory, filename))
  
  # Making a load method to load a pre-trained model
  def load(self, filename, directory):
    self.actor.load_state_dict(torch.load('%s/%s_actor.pth' % (directory, filename)))
    self.critic.load_state_dict(torch.load('%s/%s_critic.pth' % (directory, filename)))
    
#set the parameters

start_timesteps = 1e3 # Number of iterations/timesteps before which the model randomly chooses an action, and after which it starts to use the policy network
eval_freq = 5e1 # How often the evaluation step is performed (after how many timesteps)
max_timesteps = 5e3 # Total number of iterations/timesteps
save_models = True # Boolean checker whether or not to save the pre-trained model
expl_noise = 0.1 # Exploration noise - STD value of exploration Gaussian noise
batch_size = 100 # Size of the batch
discount = 0.99 # Discount factor gamma, used in the calculation of the total discounted reward
tau = 0.005 # Target network update rate
policy_noise = 0.2 # STD of Gaussian noise added to the actions for the exploration purposes
noise_clip = 0.5 # Maximum value of the Gaussian noise added to the actions (policy)
policy_freq = 2 # Number of iterations to wait before the policy network (Actor model) is updated

state_dim = 3
action_dim = 3
max_action = 1
idx = 0



class env1:
    
    def __init__(self,state_dim,action_dim,data):
        self.state_dim = state_dim
        self.state = torch.zeros(self.state_dim)
        self.state[state_dim-1]=1000.0
        self.next_state = torch.zeros(self.state_dim)
        self.next_state[state_dim-1] = 1000.0
        self.action_dim = action_dim
        self.data = data
        self.idx = 0
        self.count = 0
        self._max_episode_steps = 200
        self.state[1] = self.data[self.idx]
        self.next_state[1] = self.data[self.idx]

    def reset(self):
        self.next_state = torch.zeros(self.state_dim)
        self.next_state[state_dim-1]=1000.0
        self.state = torch.zeros(self.state_dim)
        self.state[state_dim-1]=1000.0
        self.state[1] = self.data[self.idx]
        self.next_state[1] = self.data[self.idx]
        self.count = 0
        ch = self.state[0]
        cp = self.state[1]
        cc = self.state[2]
        st = torch.tensor([ch,cp,cc])
        return st

    def step(self,action):
        done = False
        act_t = torch.argmax(action)
        self.idx += 1
        if(act_t==0):
            num_s = int(self.state[2]/self.state[1])

            self.next_state[0] += num_s
            self.next_state[2] = self.state[2]%self.state[1]

            self.next_state[1] = self.data[self.idx]
        elif(act_t==1):
            self.next_state[1] = self.data[self.idx]
        elif(act_t==2):
            self.next_state[2] = self.state[2]+ self.state[1]*self.state[0]
            self.next_state[0] = 0
            self.next_state[1] = self.data[self.idx]
            
        

        reward = self.next_state[2] - self.state[2] + self.next_state[1]*self.next_state[0] - self.state[1]*self.state[0] -1
        
        self.state[0] = self.next_state[0]
        self.state[1] = self.next_state[1]
        self.state[2] = self.next_state[2]
        
        ch = self.state[0]
        cp = self.state[1]
        cc = self.state[2]
        
        st = torch.tensor([ch,cp,cc])

        self.count = (self.count + 1)%100
        if(self.count==0):
            done = True

        return st, reward, done
policy = TD3(state_dim, action_dim, max_action)


#Create the environment
data = pd.read_csv('PAGEIND.csv')
data = data['Close']
data = np.array(data).reshape(-1,1)

max_timesteps = data.shape[0]
sc = StandardScaler()
data = sc.fit_transform(data)
data = torch.DoubleTensor(data)
env = env1(state_dim,action_dim,data)

replay_buffer = ReplayBuffer()

#init training variables
  
total_timesteps = 0
timesteps_since_eval = 0
episode_num = 0
done = True
t0 = time.time()



# We start the main loop over 500,000 timesteps
while total_timesteps < max_timesteps:

  # If the episode is done
  if done:

    # If we are not at the very beginning, we start the training process of the model
    if total_timesteps != 0:
      print("Total Timesteps: {} Episode Num: {} Reward: {}".format(total_timesteps, episode_num, episode_reward))
      policy.train(replay_buffer, episode_timesteps, batch_size, discount, tau, policy_noise, noise_clip, policy_freq)

   
    # When the training step is done, we reset the state of the environment
    obs = env.reset()
    policy.reset_hxcx()

    # Set the Done to False
    done = False
    
    # Set rewards and episode timesteps to zero
    episode_reward = 0
    episode_timesteps = 0
    episode_num += 1
  
  # Before 1000 timesteps, we play random actions
  if total_timesteps < 0.8*max_timesteps:
#random action
      actn = torch.randn(action_dim)
      action = torch.zeros(action_dim)
      action[torch.argmax(actn)] = 1
      
  else: # After 1000 timesteps, we switch to the model
    action = policy.select_action(torch.tensor(obs))
    # If the explore_noise parameter is not 0, we add noise to the action and we clip it
    if expl_noise != 0:
      print("policy action:",action)
      actn = (action + torch.randn(action_dim))
      action = torch.zeros(action_dim)
      action[torch.argmax(actn)] = 1
      
      
  # The agent performs the action in the environment, then reaches the next state and receives the reward
  new_obs, reward, done = env.step(action)
  
  # We check if the episode is done
  done_bool = 0 if episode_timesteps + 1 == env._max_episode_steps else float(done)
  
  # We increase the total reward
  episode_reward += reward
  
  # We store the new transition into the Experience Replay memory (ReplayBuffer)
  replay_buffer.add((obs, new_obs, action, reward, done_bool))

  # We update the state, the episode timestep, the total timesteps, and the timesteps since the evaluation of the policy
  obs = new_obs
  episode_timesteps += 1
  total_timesteps += 1
  timesteps_since_eval += 1
```

and below is the error msg:

```
    policy.train(replay_buffer, episode_timesteps, batch_size, discount, tau, policy_noise, noise_clip, policy_freq)

  File "C:/Users/granthjain/Desktop/startup_code/td3_lstm_try.py", line 196, in train
    next_action = self.actor_target(next_state)

  File "C:\Users\granthjain\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:/Users/granthjain/Desktop/startup_code/td3_lstm_try.py", line 79, in forward
    self.hx, self.cx = self.lstm(x, (self.hx, self.cx))

  File "C:\Users\granthjain\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\granthjain\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 708, in forward
    self.check_forward_hidden(input, hx[0], '[0]')

  File "C:\Users\granthjain\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 532, in check_forward_hidden
    input.size(0), hidden_label, hx.size(0)))

RuntimeError: Input batch size 100 doesn't match hidden[0] batch size 1
```

Comment: I have checked that hx and cx for all the lstm layers are initialised

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `nn.LSTMCell` ? This is a single computation of well.. LSTM cell. If you want to apply LSTM to the entire input you should just use `nn.LSTM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initialize your cell state and hidden state with zeros, there is no need to provide initialization at all, it will be provided for you (as a default, please see [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.LSTMCell.html)). However, should you decide to do it on your own, you should always take into account batch size (which might be different every iteration).

In the end, both cell and hidden state for `nn.LSTMCell` have shape `(batch_size, hidden_size)` whereas you initialize those once in the constructor with shape `(1, hidden_size)`. You have to move initialization to `forward()` and with each call get batch size from `x` which should be just `x.shape[0]`

---

As a side note, you are using `nn.LSTMCell` which is just a single cell computation. Used once does not really make sense, make sure that's what works for you. Maybe just `nn.LSTM` instead?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply.

I corrected the above error but am now getting error:-
RuntimeError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Can you please help a check what is wrong with the code...I assume the dimensions are correct....can it be old pytorch version problem??

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072770/pytoch-runtimeerror-dimension-out-of-range-expected-to-be-in-range-of-1-0

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply.

I tried nn.LSTM and it is way more faster.